# Plotting geom_density() computed on one variable against another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wondering if it's possible to capture the output of `geom_density()`, such that its values can be plotted against another variable in the original data frame. For example, consider some data that has been normalized to [0,1]:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)
X <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(100,-2), rnorm(100,2)),
            nx = (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
```

I would like to compute `geom_density()` on the normalized data `nx` but plot it against the original data `x`. In other words, my desired y axis is given by:

```
g1 <- ggplot( X, aes(nx) ) + geom_density()
```

[image: Desired y]

while my desired x axis is given by:

```
g2 <- ggplot( X, aes(x) ) + geom_density()
```

[image: Desired x]

Ideally, I would like to capture the y values computed by `geom_density()` as another column in my data frame `X`. But I would also settle for some way to rescale the `x` axis of `g1` or the `y` axis of `g2`, such that the resulting plot contains horizontal gridlines defined in `g1` and vertical gridlines defined in `g2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe more understandable for people not very familiar with advanced functions and to specifically use the x axis of one plot for the y data of another plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
X <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(100,-2), rnorm(100,2)),
            nx = (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))

g1 <- ggplot( X, aes(nx) ) + geom_density()
g1
g2 <- ggplot( X, aes(x) ) + geom_density()
g2

g1_build<- ggplot_build(g1) #gets all the underlying data that is ggplot uses to make the plot and stores them in a list (which is a list of lists)
g2_build<-ggplot_build(g2)#see above

#to access lists within lists use two double brackets [[]] and then the contents in a list with just []
#ggplot build of the actual coordinate values which are plotted is in the first list of the first list 
#In that list the first vector contains y values and the second contains the x values
your_data<-data.frame(x = g2_build[[1]][[1]][2], y = g1_build[[1]][[1]][1] ) #take x values of g2 plot and take y values of g1 plot and store them in a new dataframe

g_together<-ggplot(your_data, aes(x,y))+ 
  geom_line()
g_together
```

[Plot like OP wants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGD7K.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `density` and `approx` to create the y values:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
X <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(100,-2), rnorm(100,2)),
            nx = (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))

X$y <- approx(density(X$nx)$x, density(X$nx)$y, X$nx)$y

ggplot(X, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Note that this won't be as smooth as a `geom_density`, because `geom_density` will plot 512 equally-spaced sampled densities, whereas you will only have one density measurement for each x value in your data frame.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. I was considering using `density()` myself, but was wondering if there is some `stat_density()` black magic that I wasn't aware of. The smoothness issue can probably be solved by doing `geom_smooth()` instead of `geom_line()`.

Answer (score 1):

To grab the plotted values, use `ggplot_build`, then interpolate to your nx values.

```
g1_build <- ggplot_build(g1)

# interpolate to existing nx values because geom_density() returns 512 values
X <- X %>%
mutate(dens = approx(x = g1_build$data[[1]]$x, y = g1_build$data[[1]]$y, xout = nx)$y)

g3 <- ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = dens) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks, kakaoka. Did you maybe mean to write `g1_build$data` instead of `a$data`?